# Why tab key can't trigger my snipmate?

Tags: plugin-snipmate

I install pathogen to manage all plugins in gvim,do as the tutorial [hwo to install with pathogen](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) say ,running the following commands in my windows10

```
  % cd  g:\vim\vimfiles\bundle
  % git clone https://github.com/tomtom/tlib_vim.git
  % git clone https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils.git
  % git clone https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate.git
```

My _vimrc configuration:

```
set nocompatible
execute pathogen#infect()
execute pathogen#helptags()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

To edit a test.js with gvim,press `<tab>` after `for` ,no completion at all!
`:verbose imap <Tab>` shows as below:

[image]

Why `tab` key can't trigger my snipmate?

Comment: Have you installed any snippets at all? Note this section from vim-snipmate REAMDE: `SnipMate does not ship with any snippets out of the box. We suggest looking at the vim-snippets repository.`

Answer (score 1):

vim-snippets actually contains snippets not present in vim-snipmate:

```
 cd  g:\vim\vimfiles\bundle
 git clone https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets
```

Comment: Could you please write more from your own-answer?

Comment: I agree with peterh's sentiments: elaboration (e.g., that vim-snippets actually contains snippets not present in vim-snipmate) would be helpful. There's always [edit].